# "The children are happily playing" — grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, transitivity, grammar-myths

I would like to seek clarification on this sentence.

> The children are happily playing.

Is it grammatically correct? Or should there be a place as an object to follow?

Comment: Why don't you think it's correct? What made you think this? Generally on ELL you should include what research you have done, or material that's made you ask the question.

Comment: For me, *happily playing* sounds more awkward than *playing happily*. Both are perfectly correct. Personally I would say, *playing happily*  and perhaps  not even  notice that another person used *happily playing*.

Comment: @LMS, it's mentioned in the question: "Or should there be a place as an object to follow?". Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @fayazmiraz: There's no "why" (or "what") mentioned in the question, just an alternative that the asker thinks might be better. Why do they think this is better? Why do they think their original sentence is wrong? We don't know.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong in that sentence:

> The children are happily playing.

1. `The` article is used to specify a group of `children`. It's fine.
2. `are` is used as `be` verb, since `children` is plural and the verb `playing` is in present continuous form. So that part is OK too.
3. Adverb `happily` is used to modify the verb `playing`, which is fine.

Now, the question is:

> Is there a necessity for an object for the verb `playing`?

The answer is:

> No, the verb `play` does not always require an object to complete the meaning of the sentence.

You could've said, for example:

> The children are happily playing football.

However, merely mentioning that they are playing also makes complete sense. So there is nothing wrong with the sentence.

**On another note:** Even though saying `happily playing` is grammatically correct, saying `playing happily` is used more often. For example, if you look at [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=playing%20happily%2C%20happily%20playing&year_start=1960&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=5), you'll see that both were used by the authors, but `playing happily` was used more frequently:

[image: happily playing vs. playing happily]